# how to making a bar graph using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I'm pretty new to python and I'm trying to make a [bar plot using python](https://ars.els-cdn.com/content/image/1-s2.0-S0022283613004750-gr2.jpg) similar to the link using [SNAP2](https://rostlab.org/services/snap2web/) results. The results from SNAP2 is a large excel file with four columns. I want to make a bar graph plotting "Variant" on the x axis against "Expected Accuracy" on the y axis.
The initial excel file had a percent sign in each cell of the "Expected Accuracy" column and this seems to converts it to a decimal. Now I'm having some trouble actually getting it to plot as a bar graph.

```Python
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("snap2_data.xlsx", dtype={'Score': int}, sheet_name='sheet1', usecols=['Variant', 'Expected Accuracy'])

df[["Variant", "Expected Accuracy"]].plot(x="Variant", y='Expected Accuracy', kind="bar")

plt.title('Title')
plt.xlabel('Variant')
plt.ylabel('Expected Accuracy')

plt.show()
```

[image]

[image: print(df) results]

Comment: If you can provide sample data, you may be able to get answers faster.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the percent sign and convert it to a number, you get the following graph.

```
df['Expected Accuracy'] = df['Expected Accuracy'].apply(lambda x: float(x.rstrip('%')))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I've been trying to figure out how to remove the labels but have not to figure out how. is this something that is possible? I want to keep the label for the x-axis (Variant), but do not want to show the labels for each bar (M1A, M1R, etc)

Comment: `plt.xticks([])`then the label on the x-axis can be removed.